# Trouble using zoom on ggplot2 shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, zooming

I'm new here as a user but I have searched like crazy for a problem I have encountered while trying to create a data visualization app with shiny in RStudio.

The thing is, I want to read a .csv, understand it's columns, select which column I want as x and as y axis, plot them with the type of graph I have chosen and be able to zoom in in a secondary plot whenever I want.

I'm almost there, the thing is that the zoom with brush that I have tried to do is no working properly. It doesn't understand the values of the axis correctly, instead it works as if both axis where only from 0 to 1, and then zoom in the correct way but with the wrong xlim and ylim.

Here is my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

base = read.csv("TESTE.csv", sep = ";")
tipos <- c("Dispersão", "Histograma", "Boxplot", "Área")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel("MGM"),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("selectedColX", "Select colum for X axis", choices = colnames(base), selected = colnames(base)[7]),
      selectInput("selectedColY", "Select colum for Y axis", choices = colnames(base), selected = colnames(base)[4]),
      selectInput("selectedColor", "Select colum for colour axis", choices = colnames(base), selected = colnames(base)[6]),
      selectInput("seletedGraph", "Select type of graph", choices = tipos, selected = tipos[1])
    ),
    
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(width = 12, class = "well",
             h4("Left plot controls right plot"),
             fluidRow(
               column(width = 10,
                      plotOutput("Disp", height = 300,
                                 brush = brushOpts(
                                   id = "Disp_brush",
                                   clip = TRUE,
                                   resetOnNew = TRUE
                                 )
                      )
               ),
               column(width = 10,
                      plotOutput("DispZoom", height = 300)
               )
             )
      )
      
    )
    
#    mainPanel(
#      
#      plotOutput("Hist"),
#      plotOutput("Box"),
#      plotOutput("Ar")
#    )
  )
))
```

And then my Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

base = read.csv("TESTE.csv", sep = ";")
tipos <- c("Dispersão", "Histograma", "Boxplot", "Área")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$Disp <- renderPlot({
    
    validate(need(input$seletedGraph=="Dispersão", message=FALSE))
    
    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor
    
    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis))
    gg <- gg  + geom_point()
    
    plot(gg)

  })
  
  ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
  
  output$DispZoom <- renderPlot({
    
    validate(need(input$seletedGraph=="Dispersão", message=FALSE))
    
    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor
    
    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis)) + geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges2$x, ylim = ranges2$y)
    plot(gg)
    
  })
  
  output$Hist <- renderPlot({
    
    validate(need(input$seletedGraph=="Histograma", message=FALSE))
    
    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor
    
    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis))
    gg <- gg  + geom_histogram()
    gg
    
  })
  
  output$Box <- renderPlot({
    
    validate(need(input$seletedGraph=="Boxplot", message=FALSE))
    
    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor
    
    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis))
    gg <- gg  + geom_boxplot()
    gg
    
  })
  
  output$Ar <- renderPlot({
    
    validate(need(input$seletedGraph=="Área", message=FALSE))
    
    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor
    
    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis))
    gg <- gg  + geom_area()
    gg
    
  })
  
  observe({
    brush <- input$Disp_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges2$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
      
    } else {
      ranges2$x <- NULL
      ranges2$y <- NULL
    }
  })
  
})
```

Just ignore the other plots that are not the geom_point. As soon as I get this one working the others should work just fine, I guess...

Thank you so much, I'm having such a pain trying to figure this out!
Some texts are in Portuguese, but I think everything is understandable enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brushed points are on scale from 0 to 1 in the `brushOpts` because you `print` or `plot` your variable instead of just returning it.

**1. Short desmonstration**

This short app show the difference between the brushed points scales according to how it has been returned.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(6,
      # My plot rendering with print or plot
      h4("Plot with print or plot variable"),
      plotOutput("plot1", height = 300, brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush", clip = TRUE, resetOnNew = TRUE)),
      p(),
      # Brushed points
      "Brushed points informations, scale from 0 to 1",
      verbatimTextOutput("brush1")
    ),
    column(6,
      # My plot rendering without print or plot
      h4("Plot with a return variable"),
      plotOutput("plot2", height = 300, brush = brushOpts(id = "plot2_brush", clip = TRUE, resetOnNew = TRUE)),
      p(),
      # Brushed points
      "Brushed points informations, scale according to x and y variables",
      verbatimTextOutput("brush2")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- iris

  # Plot1 I render with print or plot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) + geom_point()
    plot(gg)
  })

  # Brush points from plot1
  output$brush1 <- renderPrint({
    input$plot1_brush
  })

  # Plot2 I render just returning the variable
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) + geom_point()
    return(gg)
  })

  # Brush points from plot2
  output$brush2 <- renderPrint({
    input$plot2_brush
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**2. Reproductible example from your question**

Herebelow I made a reproductible example using the `iris` dataset.
Also, I changed some characters because of accents.

*ui.R*

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("MGM"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("plots_parameters")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          h4("Plot without zoom"),
          plotOutput("Disp", height = 300, brush = brushOpts(id = "Disp_brush", clip = TRUE, resetOnNew = TRUE))
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          h4("Zoomed plot"),
          plotOutput("DispZoom", height = 300)
        )
      )
    )
  )
))
```

*server.R*

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

base = iris


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plots_parameters <- renderUI({
    tipos <- c("Dispersao", "Histograma", "Boxplot", "Área")
    choices <- colnames(base)
    div(
      selectInput("selectedColX", "Select colum for X axis", choices = choices, selected = "Sepal.Length"),
      selectInput("selectedColY", "Select colum for Y axis", choices = choices, selected = "Petal.Length"),
      selectInput("selectedColor", "Select colum for colour axis", choices = choices, selected = "Species"),
      selectInput("seletedGraph", "Select type of graph", choices = tipos, selected = "Dispersao")
    )  
  })

  output$Disp <- renderPlot({

    req(input$seletedGraph == "Dispersao")

    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor

    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis))
    gg <- gg  + geom_point()

    # Return variable without print or plot
    gg

  })

  ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  output$DispZoom <- renderPlot({

    req(input$seletedGraph == "Dispersao")

    y_axis <- input$selectedColY
    x_axis <- input$selectedColX
    color_axis <- input$selectedColor

    gg <- ggplot(base, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis, color = color_axis)) + geom_point() +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges2$x, ylim = ranges2$y)
    # Return variable without print or plot
    gg

  })

  observe({
    brush <- input$Disp_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges2$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges2$x <- NULL
      ranges2$y <- NULL
    }
  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried adding this and it still doesn't work... I'm thinking instead of doind a brush and zoom maybe it's easier to have a slider for de x and y scale? I don't know how to add a picture here to show how it's not working for me :P

Comment: You're right ! I updated my answer with a reproductible solution.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. Can you then accept my answer ?